# opening a URL in new tab

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, windows-shell

Is there a way to open a URL in a new tab (in IE) from a cpp application without using DDE or shell execute ??

Comment: In general, whether links open in a new window or a new tab is up to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you want to do something like this (error checking excluded to save me typing):

```
CoCreateInstance(CLSID_InternetExplorer, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IID_IWebBrowser2, (void**)&browser); 
browser->Navigate(bstrURL, &vEmpty, &vEmpty, &vEmpty, &vEmpty);
browser->put_Visible(VARIANT_TRUE);
```

Comment: One of the parameters (on Navigate2?) allows you to suggest if it should open in a foreground or background tab.

Answer (score 0):

You need just to send command to shell:

> shell "explorer.exe %site_path%"

This should open IE with new tab and your site.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I don't want to do a Shell launch ....
I'm basically looking for a IPC mechanism with IE (except for DDE).